# gtest :compile error

Tags: linux, gcc, googletest

When I compile gtest samples on Redhat OS(gcc version is 3.2.2),it throw the error as below,howere it compile on Ubuntu it's OK.Pleae help me.
Error or Warning:

```
../include/gtest/internal/gtest-internal.h: In instantiation of `testing::internal::ImplicitlyConvertible<const void*, const void*>':
../include/gtest/gtest-printers.h:314:   instantiated from `void testing::internal::DefaultPrintTo(char, testing::internal::bool_constant<true>, T*, std::ostream*) [with T = const void]'
../include/gtest/gtest-printers.h:376:   instantiated from `void testing::internal::PrintTo(const T&, std::ostream*) [with T = const void*]'
../include/gtest/gtest-printers.h:416:   instantiated from here
../include/gtest/internal/gtest-internal.h:890: no method `
   testing::internal::ImplicitlyConvertible<const void*, const void*>::MakeFrom
   '
../include/gtest/internal/gtest-internal.h:890: invalid use of undefined type `
   class testing::internal::ImplicitlyConvertible<const void*, const void*>'
../include/gtest/internal/gtest-internal.h:847: declaration of `class 
   testing::internal::ImplicitlyConvertible<const void*, const void*>'
```

Comment: What versions of the compiler are you using on ubuntu & redhat?

Answer (score 2):

GCC 3.2  is a compiler that's simply too old to support constructs that Google Test uses - it even predates C++ 03 standard. Try building those samples with a newer version of GCC.

Comment: Well, the [README](https://code.google.com/p/googletest/source/browse/tags/release-1.6.0/README?r=638) requires `A C++98-standard-compliant compiler`. But gcc 3.2.3 fails for me with the same error.